# Passing a Created Array Between Classes [Java]

Tags: java, class, object, scope

I'm working on a basic image manipulation program, and currently have 3 classes: Vertex, Graph, and Manipulations.

```
public class Vertex{
    //Vertex functions, including tracking neighbours
}

public class Graph{

    Vertex[][] aVertices;

    public Graph(Color[][] image){

        int xTop = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++){
            if (i > xTop){
                xTop = i;
            }
        }    

        int yTop = image.length;

        Vertex[][] aVertices = new Vertex[xTop][yTop];

        for(int i = 0; i < xTop; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < yTop; j++){
                Vertex newVertex = new Vertex(i, j, image[i][j]);
                aVertices[i][j] = newVertex;
            }
        }    

        for(int i = 0; i < xTop; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < yTop; j++){
                if(aVertices[i][j] == aVertices[i-1][j]){
                    aVertices[i][j].neighbourize(aVertices[i-1][j]);
                }
                if(aVertices[i][j] == aVertices[i+1][j]){
                    aVertices[i][j].neighbourize(aVertices[i+1][j]);
                }
                if(aVertices[i][j] == aVertices[i][j-1]){
                    aVertices[i][j].neighbourize(aVertices[i][j-1]);    
                }
                if(aVertices[i][j] == aVertices[i][j+1]){
                    aVertices[i][j].neighbourize(aVertices[i][j+1]);
                }
            }
        }

    }

}

public class Manipulations{

    //Image manipulations that access aVertices    

}
```

As you can see, upon creation of the graph, a 2D array is created that holds vertex objects, which are then assigned appropriate neighbour statuses with shared colours. I now want to take this entire aVertices and work on it inside of Manipulations, but am not really sure how to move it within the appropriate scope. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Note that you have two variables named `aVertices`. I suggest you learn the difference between the two and how they can cause problems for you. (Note one is a **field variable** and the other is a **local variable**. These two terms can help you find more information.)

Comment: How do you create objects of each class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are lack of the knowledge of [Object Oriented Programming](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objektorientierte_Programmierung).

For your question, you can define such method in `Graph`.

```
public Vertex[][] getVertices() {
  return this.aVertices;
}
```

In `Manipulations`, you can get `aVertices` with

```
Graph g = new Graph(image);
Vertex[][] vertices = g.getVertices();
```

Comment: Yes, I'm still fairly new to object oriented programming, thank you for a god answer! I'll accept it when possible.

Comment: Here is a useful [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/).